# Move selected object with transformation matrix

Tags: transform-orientation, matrix

I'm working on a script which exports geometry and structure data (BOM and position) from CATIA V5 into blender.

Catia V5 delivers as an *absolute position* for each part an array with 12 elements. 9 values are reserved for the rotation matrix and 3 values are used for the shift. Applying this transformation to the *initial position* of the part places the part in the final position.

$$
\text{Catia Array} = \begin{pmatrix}
R_1 \\ R_2 \\ R_3 \\ R_4 \\ R_5 \\ R_6 \\ R_7 \\ R_8 \\ R_9 \\ T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

To apply a movement on a part and change the position with $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$ along the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axis, is easy:

```
bpy.context.object.location[0] = T1
bpy.context.object.location[1] = T2
bpy.context.object.location[2] = T2
```

The problem is much more to use the values $R_1  \dots R_9$ because blender handles very well elementary rotations but so far I know not a whole rotation matrix.
An elementary rotation is a rotation about one of the axes of a coordinate system by an angle $\alpha$ or $\beta$ or $\gamma$, which has to be given.
If the are given, you can change the location:

```
bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[0] = angle1
bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[1] = angle2
bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[2] = angle2
```

The rotation matrix $R$ is a multiplication of matrices of elementary rotations
$$R = R_z(\alpha) \; R_y(\beta) \; R_x (\gamma)$$

But what I have are not the angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$, but the whole matrix $R$ which could look like:

$\text{values for rotation} = \begin{matrix}0.23 & 0.81 & 0.14 \\ 0.54 & 0.91 & 0.45 \\ 0.12 & 0.03 & 0.24  \end{matrix}$

I want to apply this transformation on a selected object in so less steps as possible. In the best case in two steps: 1st rotation with $R$ and 2nd linear shift with $T$.
I also want to apply this rotation in so less steps as possible, and I want to avoid to decompose the matrix $R$ in elementary rotations.

Is there any possibility to apply a rotation on a selected object without creating elementars rotations $R_z(\alpha)$,  $ R_y(\beta) $, $ R_x (\gamma)$?

Until now I found the following method:

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(78.53, 450.56, 52.0), orient_type='GLOBAL',orient_matrix=((0.23, 0.81, 0.14), (0.54, 0.91, 0.45), (0.12, 0.03, 0.24)),orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL')
```

But this delivers no proper movement.

For the worst case I would be happy if anyone could offer a good method in numpy to decompose the matrix $R$

Comment: I'm no expert, so this may or may not be of use, however, I noticed that your T matrix is a Vector3 and might be treated as such. In searching for clarification, I came upon this post. It's not for blender specifically, but is language-agnostic as it only applies to vectors and matrices. Have a look and see if any of it makes sense to you. It seems that if you are able to convert both (T and R) into 4x4 matrices, you can apply both the transforms and rotations all at once by multiplying them. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944670/method-of-transforming-3d-vectors-with-a-matrix

Comment: similarly `M = R.to_4x4()` and `M.translation = T` will give the global transform matrix.  `ob.matrix_world = M`  Recommend not using `bpy.ops` to transform.  Also `R.to_euler()` is the Euler rep'n of that rotation in default mode ('XYZ')